# How to increase the rate of broadcasting

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have written a base_link to map broadcaster and I am trying to increase the rate of broadcasting to 50 hz.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>

void poseCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr& msg){
  static tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;
  tf::Transform transform;
  transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(-msg->pose.position.x, -msg->pose.position.y, -msg->pose.position.z));
  transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(-msg->pose.orientation.x, -msg->pose.orientation.y, -msg->pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.orientation.w));
  broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "base_link", "map"));
  ROS_INFO("Broadcasting between map and base_link successful !!!");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_broadcaster_node");

  ros::NodeHandle node;
  ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe("/slam_out_pose", 7, &poseCallback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
};
```

How can I do that ?

I checked the [tf::Transform::sendTransform](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformBroadcaster.html) member function but I didn't find an input for that.

I also wanted to ask if is there another way to broadcast the connection from base_link to map ?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242142/how-to-increase-the-rate-of-broadcasting/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try this:

```
  void poseCallback(){
     modify your transform......
  }
  int main(){
    ros::Rate rate(50.0);
    ....
    while (node.ok()){
    send your transform.....
    rate.sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();
    }
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-08-22**:
or use a Timer callback.